# Reduce big-O complexity in sorting algorithm

Tags: algorithm, loops, iteration, big-o

I made the acquaintance of big-O a couple of weeks ago and am trying to get to grips with it, but although there's a lot of material out there about calculating time complexity, I can't seem to find out how to make algorithms more efficient.

I've been practicing with the the demo challenge in Codility:

> Write a function that, given an array A of N integers, returns the smallest >positive integer (greater than 0) that does not occur in A. For example, given A = [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2], the function should return 5.
>   The given array can have integers between -1 million and 1 million.

I started with a brute-force algorithm:

```
public int solution(int[] A)
        {
            for ( int number = 1; number < 1000000; number ++)
            {
                if (doesContain(A, number)){}
                else return i;
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

This passed all tests for correctness but scored low on performance because the running time was way past the limit, time complexity being O(N**2).

I then tried putting the array into an arraylist, which reduces big-O since each object is "touched" only once, and I can use .Contains which is more efficient than iteration (not sure if that's true; I just sort of remember reading it somewhere).

```
public int solution(int[] A)
    {
        ArrayList myArr = new ArrayList();
        for (int i=0; i<A.Length; i++)
        {
            myArr.Add(A[i]);
        }
        for ( int i = 1; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            if (myArr.Contains(i)){}
            else return i;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Alas, the time complexity is still at O(N**2) and I can't find explanations of how to cut down time.

I know I shouldn't be using brute force, but can't seem to think of any other ways... Anyone have an explanation of how to make this algorithm more efficient?

Comment: Off the top of my head: You can sort the array descending (which can be *O(n log n)*) and then iterate until `array[i + 1] < array[i] - 1`.

Comment: @Marvin Not quite, this would return 7 for `[6, 8]`, when it should return 1. I'd discard any value `<=0`, then sort in ascending order, and then iterate to return the first index `i` where `sorted_array[i] 1= i`. Still *O(n log n)* for sorting.

Comment: If you let *k* be the max int allowed (1000000 in the question), you can also solve it in *O(max(k,n))* by creating a array `flag[]` of *k+1* bits initialized to all false except `flag[0]`. Iterate through the array and set `flag[array[i]]` if `array[i]>0`. Then find the first `i` such that `flag[i]` is not set. For fastest results, use the sorted array algorithm if *k < n log n* else the flag algorithm.

Comment: Note that since the numbers are integers, sorting can be done in order n using some form of radix sort. Once you have them ordered, then compute the minimum of the complement (on the positive numbers), which can be done in order n too.

Comment: @aligur good point, and with the max being known, radix sort will have a known number of iterations.

Comment: If you use an in-place radix sort, then the space complexity can be made constant. The order of growth of the number of steps of the algorithm cannot be made smaller than n, because all n elements can affect the solution, so they need to be processed.

Comment: @joanis: Ah yeah, my bad. Somehow I misread the task. But the general idea should still have become clear.

Comment: Might be a question suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical interview question.  Forget the sort; this is a detection problem, **O(n + m)** on `n` elements and a max value of `m` (which is given as a constant).

```
boolean found[1000000] = False  /// set all elements to false

for i in A    // check all items in the input array
    if i > 0
        found[i] = True

for i in (0, 1000000)
    if not found[i]
        print "Smallest missing number is", i
```